# How to write an app launcher that launches apps based on defined schedules

Tags: vb.net, scheduler, launch

I must write an application where I can define programs to run at certain times, on certain days, and run at certain intervals.

1. A.exe must run on the 1st and 15th day of each month at 8:00am.
2. B.exe must run on the 16th and 31st of each month at 8:30am. If the
   month doesn't have 31 days, then run the 31st instance on the last
   day of the month.
3. C.exe must run on the 1st and 3rd Monday of each
   month at 9:00am
4. D.exe must run every weekday at 4:00am, and every 30
   minutes after that until 11:00pm.

I need to be able to look at the LastRunTime of each task and figure out the NextRunTime.

I'm looking for suggestions/directions on how best to approach writing this algorithm. I was thinking of parsing an input string like the following:

```
DayOfMonth=1,15;StartTime=00:00:01;EndTime=23:59:59;Interval=1:30:00
or 
DayOfWeek=Mon,1,3|Wed,2,4;StartTime=00:00:01;EndTime=23:59:59;Interval=1:30:00
or
DayOfWeek=Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri;StartTime=08:00:00;EndTime=23:00:00;Interval=00:30:00
```

The 2nd string says 1st & 3rd Monday of each month and the 2nd & 4th Wed of each month.

The 3rd string says basically every weekday.

I'll have the UI allow the user to set the parameters and it'll generate the string to pass to the task handler.

I had started writing code to parse the "DayOfMonth" string, it's untested and I realized that it doesn't take into account if the month has less days than the day number its supposed to run on. Here it is:

```
Private Sub GetNextRuntime()
    Dim st As Date
    If ScheduleValue("DayOfMonth") <> "" Then
        For Each s As String In ScheduleValue("DayOfMonth").Split(",")
            If IsNumeric(s) Then
                If CInt(s) >= Now.Day Then
                    If IsDate(ScheduleValue("StartTime")) Then
                        st = CDate(ScheduleValue("StartTime"))
                        If st.TimeOfDay >= Now.TimeOfDay Then
                            NextRunTime = New Date(st.Year, st.Month, st.Day, st.Hour, st.Minute, st.Second)
                            Exit Sub
                        ElseIf LastRunTime.Date <> Now.Date Then
                            NextRunTime = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, Now.Hour, Now.Minute, Now.Second).AddMinutes(Rnd(0, 59))
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Else
                        Throw New Exception("Invalid StartTime value for Task id " & TaskId)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Invalid DayOfMonth value in Task Id " & TaskId)
            End If
        Next
        st = CDate(ScheduleValue("StartTime"))
        NextRunTime = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, CInt(ScheduleValue("DayOfMonth").Split(",")(0)), st.Hour, st.Minute, st.Second).AddMonths(1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ScheduleValue(ByVal ParamName As String) As String
    With New Regex(ParamName & "=(?<Value>.*?);")
        If .IsMatch(Schedule) Then
            ScheduleValue = .Match(Schedule).Groups("Value").Value
        Else
            ScheduleValue = ""
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I'll add that the app launcher program will get impersonation credentials from a database and launch the tasks with those credentials. It'll be set up on an auto-login pc and will launch on startup. This is because we want to see the apps (all console apps) as they are running.

Answer (score 0):

Personally the best way (most fail safe) to handle a proccess like this is either to write a service that is continually running in the background, but since your run times are so far away  I would add a scheduled task so that windows launches your app and have your app set the following scheduled task on construction.

see - [Setting up a scheduled task in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301531/setting-up-a-scheduled-task-in-net)

Comment: Thanks. But i'm looking for guidance on how to write the algorithm to determine next run time based on last run time and the scheduling parameters.  The rest is already decided.

Comment: Well from your example, it looks like its only a & b you have to handle c & d would focus on thier own pattern something like                                      'if(day =1){ A();}  A->nexttask = (month/2) B->nexttask = A->nexttask +1 (once they done)B->nexttask = (lastday(month))