# Run code every hour of the hour

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I want to execute a code every hour on the hour plus `3 mins` on the `form_load`. I wrote some code but it is not enough for my aim. For example if I open the application at `8:10`, I want it to execute at `9:03`, `10:03`, `11:03` and so on.

What is the best approach for this? I tried using Timer with the code below.

```
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim minutesLeft = 60 - currentDate.Minute 'Computes how many minutes left until an hour
    Dim toMilisecs = (minutesLeft + 3) * 60000 'Convert (mins + 3) to milisecs
    tmrDPL.Interval = toMilisecs 'Set tmrDPL.Interval to toMilisecs


    If tmrDPL.Interval = 180000 Then 'Execute every hh:03 hr
        'Execute code
    End If
```

Comment: This is interesting, I just want to put an idea out there, if you place your code in an office file like this, you need to have the file open and running for the code to run. It may be worth moving your code to VBScript (which is close to VBA (late bound)) and then set a scheduled task to run

Comment: is it a windows forms or office application? `vba` tag and `form_load` event don't match

Comment: @S.Serp this is a windows form

Comment: This is what scheduled tasks are for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up a scheduled task in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301531/setting-up-a-scheduled-task-in-net)

Comment: also : [Create scheduled task using VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20677722/327083)

Comment: is your application open for all the time you need to execute thath code?

Comment: @S.Serp Yes it is.

Comment: Look into the timer.tick event; this is how you run code with the timer. And dont forget to start the timer with timer.start

Comment: This has changed from a VBA question to something else, so I can take my answer down as it doesn't relate, J still has a lesson in manners\etiquette to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the question @Odie.  Since you have an answer, but the question is a duplicate, I am going to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with a more accurate calculation of the start-time.
Because the answer of S. Serp is not starting the timer exactly at `**:03`, but depending on the start-time of the app at `**:03:59` for example.

```vb
Private Sub InitTimer()
    Dim currDate As DateTime = Date.Now
    Dim startMinute As Integer = 3
    Dim startTime As New TimeSpan(currDate.Hour, startMinute, 0)
    Dim secondsToNextRun As Integer = (3600 + startMinute * 60) -
                                     ((currDate.Minute * 60) + currDate.Second +
                                     If(currDate.TimeOfDay.Ticks > startTime.Ticks, 0, 3600))

    'calculate ms from s (add 1ms, for the case that secondsToNextRun = 0)
    tmrDLP.Interval = secondsToNextRun * 1000 + 1
    tmrDLP.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub tmrDLP_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrDLP.Tick
    If tmrDLP.Interval <> 3600000 Then
        tmrDLP.Interval = 3600000
    End If

    'run your code here
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this mean that when I run the app at `8:00` it will execute the code at `8:03`?

Comment: Yes. And what i wanna say is, that when you run S.Serg's code at `08:30:59` for example. It will run next at `09:03:59` instead of `09:03:00`.

Comment: The 60000 value in tick event must be `3600000` to convert an hour to msec. It seems it was my typo which is copied to your answer ;D

Comment: @S.Serp LOL :-D, you're right. Copy & Paste is dangerous. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Edited: (consider when cur time minute is before xx:03)

You can use a timer and adjust its interval after first call as following:

in form_load:

```
Dim t As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim m as Integer = t.Minute
If m < 3 Then 
    m = 3 - m 'we should call timer soon before next hour
Else
    m = (60 - m) + 3 'here (60-m) counts minutes left in this hour
    If m = 3 Then DoMyTasks() 'execute your code... 'remove this based on your needs!
End If

tmrDPL.Interval = (m * 60 - t.Second) * 1000 'specify first interval in millisec.
```

and in timer `tick` event:

```
If tmrDPL.Interval <> 3600000 Then '60*60*1000
    tmrDPL.Interval = 3600000 'next calls must be after one hour from now
End If
DoMyTasks() 'execute your code...
```

Comment: This won't work in every case. If the app is started for example at `08:01`, the first run will be at `09:03` instead of `08:03`.

Comment: @MatSnow code updated to consider when current time minute is before xx:03

Comment: Maybe this doesn't matter for OP, but it won't start exactly at `**:03`, depending on the starttime of the app, the timer will always run for example at `**:03:59`.

Comment: @MatSnow yes, it was a quick code to show the main point about time intervals... Easily updated by `... - t.Second` to include also seconds

Answer (score 1):

This goal isn't this easy to achieve with just a few lines of code. To do it clean you have to check if you already passed the trigger point, not just if you are hitting it just now. I wrote a minimal class to just do this. Use it if you want or adapt it to match your needs.

```vb
Public Class OffsetTimer
    Private cycle As Long
    Private offset As Long
    Private nextTrigger As Long

    Public Sub New(Byval initCycle As Long, Byval initOffset As Long)
        cycle = initCycle
        offset = initOffset

        'Calculate next trigger point
        nextTrigger = offset + ((Date.Now.Ticks /  cycle) * cycle)
        While(Date.Now.Ticks >= nextTrigger) 'If next trigger time still is in the past...
            'offset was to small, so add an additional cycle
            nextTrigger = nextTrigger + cycle
        End While
    End Sub

    Public Function CheckTrigger as Boolean
        Dim retVar As Boolean
        Dim ticks As Long

        retVar = False
        ticks = Date.Now.Ticks

        'If trigger point lies in presence or even past...
        If nextTrigger <= ticks Then
            'Prepare Return True
            retVar = True
            'Calculate next trigger point
            nextTrigger = nextTrigger + cycle
        End If

        Return retVar
    End Function
End Class
```

The `CheckTrigger` function returns `True` if the `nextTrigger` time has been reached.

You also can use a similar calculation to get the time until the next trigger point(`Date.Now.Ticks - nextTrigger` for example) and just set an `Timer`'s interval to it.
If you still have some questions, just leave it in the comments.